# Passing arrays to lua as function argument from Fortran

Tags: arrays, lua, fortran, lua-table

I am looking for Fortran examples (also interface function) to pass arrays as arguments to lua functions. I was able to use [fortlua project](https://github.com/adolgert/FortLua) to start. But the example provided passes one element at a time. Appreciate any help.

```lua
--Lua code 

local q1
local q2
function getoutput( qout1, qout2)
-- qout1 and qout2 are arrays with some dimension
  q1 = qout1
  q2 = qout2
end
```

-- in fortran I used

```pascal
config_function('getoutput', args, 2, cstatus)
```

But setting the args is where I am looking for some help. The following code does the job for scalar argument variable not an array I guess.

```pascal
!> Evaluate a function in the config file and get its result.
FUNCTION config_function(name,args,nargs,status)
    REAL :: config_function
    CHARACTER(LEN=*) :: name
    REAL, DIMENSION(nargs) :: args
    REAL(KIND=c_double) :: anarg
    INTEGER :: nargs
    INTEGER :: status
    INTEGER :: iargs
    INTEGER(c_int) :: stackstart

    stackstart = lua_gettop(mluastate)

    config_function = 0
    status = 0


    CALL lua_getglobal(mluastate,TRIM(name)//C_NULL_CHAR)
    IF ( lua_type(mluastate,-1) .eq. LUA_TFUNCTION ) THEN
        DO iargs = 1,nargs
          anarg = args(iargs)
          CALL lua_pushnumber(mluastate,anarg)
        ENDDO
        IF (lua_pcall(mluastate,nargs,1,0) .eq. 0) THEN
          if (lua_isnumber(mluastate,-1) .ne. 0) THEN
            config_function = lua_tonumber(mluastate,-1)
            CALL lua_settop(mluastate,-2)
          ELSE
            ! Nothing to pop here
            status=-3
          ENDIF
        ELSE
          CALL lua_settop(mluastate,-2)
          status=-2
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        CALL lua_settop(mluastate,-2)
        status=-1
    ENDIF
    IF (stackstart .ne. lua_gettop(mluastate)) THEN
       WRITE(*,*) 'The stack is a different size coming out of config_function'
    ENDIF
END FUNCTION config_function
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: You could push stuff into a table, and then pass this table to the function. However, you still would probably push the elements one-by-one into the table. I guess, if you are looking into large chunks of data, it might be better to use userdata, though this might get pretty involved. In aotus we also use the putting of individual scalars onto the stack, though you can loop over an arbitrary number of elements: https://geb.sts.nt.uni-siegen.de/doxy/aotus/module/aot_fun_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little bit on my comment, here is a small program implementing an array argument with the help of [Aotus](https://bitbucket.org/apesteam/aotus):

```
program aot_vecarg_test
  use flu_binding, only: flu_State, flu_settop

  use aotus_module, only: open_config_file, close_config
  use aot_fun_module, only: aot_fun_type, aot_fun_do, &
    &                       aot_fun_put, aot_fun_open, &
    &                       aot_fun_close
  use aot_references_module, only: aot_reference_for, aot_reference_to_top
  use aot_table_module, only: aot_table_open, aot_table_close, &
    &                         aot_table_from_1Darray

  implicit none

  type(flu_State) :: conf
  type(aot_fun_type) :: luafun
  integer :: iError
  character(len=80) :: ErrString
  real :: args(2)
  integer :: argref
  integer :: arghandle

  args(1) = 1.0
  args(2) = 2.0

  call create_script('aot_vecarg_test_config.lua')
  write(*,*)
  write(*,*) 'Running aot_vecarg_test...'
  write(*,*) ' * open_config_file (aot_vecarg_test_config.lua)'
  call open_config_file(L = conf, filename = 'aot_vecarg_test_config.lua', &
    &                   ErrCode = iError, ErrString = ErrString)
  if (iError /= 0) then
    write(*,*) ' : unexpected FATAL Error occured !!!'
    write(*,*) ' : Could not open the config file aot_ref_test_config.lua:'
    write(*,*) trim(ErrString)
    STOP
  end if
  write(*,*) '  : success.'

  ! Create a table with data
  call aot_table_from_1Darray( L       = conf,      &
    &                          thandle = arghandle, &
    &                          val     = args       )
  ! Create a reference to this table
  call flu_setTop(L = conf, n = arghandle)
  argref = aot_reference_for(L = conf)

  ! Start the processing of the function
  call aot_fun_open(L = conf, fun = luafun, key = 'print_array')
  ! Put the previously defined table onto the stack by using the reference
  call aot_reference_to_top(L = conf, ref = argref)
  ! Put the top of the stack to the argument list of the Lua function
  call aot_fun_put(L = conf, fun = luafun)
  ! Execute the Lua function
  call aot_fun_do(L = conf, fun = luafun, nresults = 0)
  call aot_fun_close(L = conf, fun = luafun)

  write(*,*) ' * close_conf'
  call close_config(conf)
  write(*,*) '  : success.'
  write(*,*) '... Done with aot_vecarg_test.'
  write(*,*) 'PASSED'

contains

  subroutine create_script(filename)
    character(len=*) :: filename

    open(file=trim(filename), unit=22, action='write', status='replace')
    write(22,*) '-- test script for vectorial argument'
    write(22,*) 'function print_array(x)'
    write(22,*) '  for i, num in ipairs(x) do'
    write(22,*) '    print("Lua:"..num)'
    write(22,*) '  end'
    write(22,*) 'end'
    close(22)
  end subroutine create_script

end program aot_vecarg_test
```

This makes use of a little helping routine [aot_table_from_1Darray](https://geb.sts.nt.uni-siegen.de/doxy/aotus/interface/aot_table_from_1darray.html) that creates a Lua table for an array of real numbers. Have a look at its code to see how data can be put into a table.

We then create a reference to this table to easily look it up later on and pass it as an argument to the Lua function.
The example creates the corresponding Lua script itself, which defines a simple function that expects a single table as input and prints each of the tables entries. Running this yields the following output:

```
 Running aot_vecarg_test...
  * open_config_file (aot_vecarg_test_config.lua)
   : success.
Lua:1.0
Lua:2.0
  * close_conf
   : success.
 ... Done with aot_vecarg_test.
 PASSED
```

Where the two lines starting with Lua are written by the Lua function print_array.

There are other possible solutions, but I hope this gives at least some idea on how this could be done. We could also think about extending the `aot_fun_put` interface to take care of arrays itself.

Comment: @kumar with https://bitbucket.org/apesteam/aotus/commits/eb52ed11e6c1c71b2d66f667010995707df81a88 it is now also possible to pass arrays to functions as tables like this: real :: args(2); call aot_fun_put(L, fun, args). As described above this still involves putting each entry of the array individually into the table and is probably not advisable for large amounts of data, but for small vectors it should do.